# How to insert into sql table from an array of variables in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

USING JAVA ECLIPSE
Actually am having an SQL table of 13 attributes. Into that I want to insert a data stored in a Integer array variable the array name is numbers

So is my way of storing into the sql table correct?

```
  try {
                String query="insert into present values (numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2],numbers[3],numbers[4],numbers[5],numbers[6],numbers[7],numbers[8],numbers[9],numbers[10],numbers[11],numbers[12],numbers[13])";
                PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved");
                pst.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Try this: `String query="insert into present values ("+numbers[0]+","+numbers[1]+","+numbers[2]+","+numbers[3]+","+numbers[4]+","+numbers[5]+","+numbers[6]+","+numbers[7]+","+numbers[8]+","+numbers[9]+","+numbers[10]+","+numbers[11]+","+numbers[12]+","+numbers[13]+")";`

Answer (score 0):

assuming your array have only 14 elements - means `numbers.length` is 14.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO present VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);

for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    pst.setInt(i+1, numbers[i]);

pst.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Insert statement should probably include the names of the columns (sql standard), but regrading the parameters: the query string should hold a question mark for each dynamic parameter, and then you invoke pst.setInt (or whichever "set" matches your values). In your case, you can call the setters in a loop, doing something like the following:

```
String query="insert into present (column names...) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);

for(int i=0;i<13;i++)
{
    pst.setInt(i+1, numbers[i]);
}

pst.execute();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved");
pst.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```